# Return a Reference to a Class with Static Methods and Static Fields Without Instantiation

Tags: java

I want to create a wrapper class that calls static methods and member fields from a class that is provided by a library I am unable to view the code.

This is to avoid boilerplate setting code of the global member fields when I need to use a static method in a specific context.

I want to try to avoid creating wrapper methods for each static method.

My question:

Is it possible to return a class with static methods from a method to access just the static methods without instantiating it?

Code is below with comments in-line.

The code is used to demonstrate a change in a static value when the method `getMath()` is invoked.

I want to avoid the setting of the value before calling the static method.

```
StaticMath.setFirstNumber(1);
StaticMath.calc(1);

StaticMath.setFirstNumber(2);
StaticMath.calc(1);
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE and it comes up with Warnings, which I understand, but want to avoid.

I tried searching for something on this subject, so if anyone can provide a link I can close this.

```
public class Demo {
    // Static Methods in a class library I don't have access to. 
    static class StaticMath {
        private static int firstNum;

        private StaticMath() {  
        }

        public static int calc(int secondNum) {
            return firstNum + secondNum;
        }

        public static void setFirstNumber(int firstNum) {
            StaticMath.firstNum = firstNum;
        }
    }

    // Concrete Class
    static class MathBook {
        private int firstNum;

        public MathBook(int firstNum) {
            this.firstNum = firstNum;
        }

        // Non-static method that gets the class with the static methods.
        public StaticMath getMath() {
            StaticMath.setFirstNumber(firstNum);
            // I don't want to instantiate the class.
            return new StaticMath();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        MathBook m1 = new MathBook(1);
        MathBook m2 = new MathBook(2);

        // I want to avoid the "static-access" warning.
        // Answer is 2
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(m1.getMath().calc(1)));
        // Answer is 3
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(m2.getMath().calc(1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `StaticMath.calc(1)`

Comment: This design (to set `firstNum`) is bad, a class with only static methods should be stateless

Comment: @JoopEggen When m1 and m2 are instantiated the `firstNum` value is set to 1 and 2 respectively. The issue is I need to call `StaticMath.setFirstNumber()` before calling `StaticMath.calc()`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english - I don't understand how you could use a library if you don't have access to said library?

Comment: @Rhayene Library is accessible, but I can't change the code. The methods are provided as static and the member fields are suspected to be static as well.

Comment: Use a decompiler (like built-in in IntelliJ) to check the source code.

Comment: Assuming you cannot change the lib and **have to** use it: You **must** make calling `setFirstNumber` and `calc` one single atomic operation! Otherwise you'll get into serious trouble as soon as 2 threads start using that stuff concurrently!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt call a static method through an object reference. You should directly use class reference to call a static method like this:

```
StaticMath.calc(1)
```

But if you still need it for some reason, you can return null in getMath method, but you will still get warning in Eclipse:

```
public StaticMath getMath() {
    StaticMath.setFirstNumber(firstNum);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `You should call a static method through an object reference` ??? or you meant `should not`  ?

Comment: @JasonTolotta Do you release having such a design is very bad especially if you use it in a multi threaded environment? Your objects are referencing the same static value which will cause wrong calculations. Static methods should get all parameters as method arguments to avoid such cases

Comment: @Tanrikut Let's say the environment is not multi-threaded and the setting of said Static Variables is more for a convenience.

Comment: Ok, although it seems still weird but I can suggest _return null_ in getMath method so you dont create a new object but still reference static methods

Comment: @Tanrikut Yah, this solves the issue of accessing the class without instantiation from another class' non-static method. Pity about the Eclipse message. I think you win.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just wrap it to make for an atomic operation:

```
public static class MyMath{

    public static synchronized int myCalc( int num1 , int num2 ){
         StaticMath.setFirstNum(num1);
         return StaticMath.calc(num2);
    }

}
```

Drawback: You'll have to make sure, `StaticMath` is not used avoiding this "bridging" class.

Usage:

```
int result1 = MyMath.myCalc( 1, 1 );
int result1 = MyMath.myCalc( 2, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I infer that question is not properly asked if the answer is not

```
   StaticMath.calc(1)
```

Other issue you may be facing due to package visibility to static inner classes. Which is a design choice by the writer of Demo class. If you can mark your classes MathBook and StaticMath public then you can access them like below:

```
   Demo.StaticMath.calc(1);
```

Comment: Yah, let's imagine that the inner classes are in separate files.